# .NET: Overhead of Threading

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, marshalling

Suppose I have two threads: A and B. When A creates an object(for example a List of String), and passes it to B for processing. Will there a performance decrease for each time B access this object? Or will there be a one-time penalty while the object is marshalled from A to B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no marshalling between threads in .NET. Both threads will interact with the same memory for storage associated with the object. There is no performance overhead for having one thread rather than another perform an operation on the object.

You need to worry about synchronisation between threads to ensure thread safety, not performance.

Comment: Doesn't marshaling occur if thread A is a UI thread? In that case, thread B cannot directly access the object. And using Invoke to run a delegate on the UI thread would result in marshaling?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is any marshalling - no objects are copied. The need to ensure that calls to certain UI-related objects are made on a UI thread is because some underlying Win32 resources assoociated with UI elements have thread affinity and should only be called by the thread which created them.

Answer (score 3):

The threads live in the same memory space, so there is no marshalling, and no penalty for accessing objects.

However, as they share the memory you have to synchronise the access to the objects so that anything that is ever changed is only accessed by one thread at a time. When one thread is accessing an object the other thread has to wait, so that will cause a bit of overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you are using multiple threads in .Net does not imply marshaling will be used. Marshaling comes into play when you are sharing objects across AppDomains.

Assuming there are no AppDomains then the overhead you would pay would be locking - making sure only one thread accesses the object at a time. Each time you lock and unlock an object it will take up some CPU cycles.

Using multiple threads can also add other penalties - for example if you have to swap from thread A to thread B to complete some task then there may be the penalty of a thread switch. If the CPU has to put thread A to bed and wake up thread B then there will be some processor cycles spent doing this. Even if thread A and thread B are running on different CPUs but modifying common data then data in the CPU caches may have to be discarded (cache sloshing). Just a warning that you might try to speed something up by processing in parallel but end up slowing your app down.

Marshaling would be used if you are accessing an object created in one .Net AppDomain from another. And, depending on the type of marshaling you are using you could either go for the one time penalty (marshal by value) or the per call penalty (marshal by reference).